# How to select a value of a key in dictionary based on the value of another key

Tags: python, dictionary

In the following dictionary:

```
dic = {'x':[1, 2, 3], 'y':[11, 12 , 13]}
```

I want to retrieve the value `2` from the list corresponding to the key `'x'`, when the element of the list corresponding to the key `'y'` is `12`.

Comment: So you want to select the second element because the second element of y is 12? What is the relation between 2 and 12?

Comment: As written, dic['y'] is a list rather than the number 12. Is this intended?

Comment: @RaySteam: Yes, I want to select to select 2 in x when y is 12, and there is no relationship between the keys x and y.

Comment: @cischa. Yes it is a list. I must amend the text.

Comment: @MarcoC are they ordered? i.e. value at index 1 at `y` maps to value at index 1 at `x`?

Comment: What is the relationship between the `12` and the `y` list and the `2` in the `x` list? From your example, I assume it is based on the position in the list. Is that correct?

Comment: @oneturkmen Yes, they are ordered.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Yes, it is correct.

Comment: Are values in list `y` unique?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A flexible solution is to create a lookup dictionary based on the values in `dic`:

```
>>> dic = {'x':[1, 2, 3], 'y':[11, 12 , 13]}
>>> lookup = dict(zip(dic['y'], dic['x']))
>>> lookup
{11: 1, 12: 2, 13: 3}
>>> lookup[12]
2
```

Comment: if used multiple time this is defenitly a great solution. If used once a simpler version is just dic['x'][ dic['y'].index(12) ]

Answer (score 1):

If you want an `x` based on the position of a given `y`, I suggest using `zip()`:

```
def find_x(dic, target_y):
    pairs = zip(dic['x'], dic['y'])
    for x, y in pairs:
        if y == target_y:
            return x
```

In fact, if you are doing this kind of thing often. It would be best to store your x and y values as a list of pairs (or dictionaries or class objects) rather than a dictionary with separate x and y lists.

Comment: On your recommendation, for OP’s purposes it may actually be better to structure it as a dictionary with keys of y, and values of the corresponding x.

Comment: @KieranMoynihan I just saw Selcuk's answer. That is definitely an elegant way to do it.